# Flutter - storing data localy and accesing them from another users phone

Tags: android, database, flutter, data-storage

I´am just starting flutter and wanted to ask for a posibility of tracking variable from another users interface

Can I somehow access and pass simple int variable changess via wifi F.E. or do i need to use some backend like firebase.

Thank you !

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably take a look at UDP i.e. User Datagram Protocol. The UDP protocol allows the computer applications to send the messages in the form of datagrams from one machine/device to another over the Internet Protocol.

In Flutter there is a package which can allow you to do this, you can check it out here [Link to package](https://pub.dev/packages/udp) and explore the possibilities of what you require.

The below code shows an example of the how the package works:

```
    import 'package:udp/udp.dart';

    main() async {
    // creates a UDP instance and binds it to the first available network
    // interface on port 65000.
    var sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any(port: Port(65000)));

    // send a simple string to a broadcast endpoint on port 65001.
    var dataLength = await sender.send("Hello World!".codeUnits,
    Endpoint.broadcast(port: Port(65001)));
  
    stdout.write("$dataLength bytes sent.");
  
    // creates a new UDP instance and binds it to the local address and the port
    // 65002.
    var receiver = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.loopback(port: Port(65002)));
  
    // receiving\listening
    receiver.asStream(timeout: Duration(seconds: 20)).listen((datagram) {
      var str = String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data);
      stdout.write(str);
    });
  
    // close the UDP instances and their sockets.
    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
  
  
   // MULTICAST
    var multicastEndpoint =
        Endpoint.multicast(InternetAddress("239.1.2.3"), port: Port(54321));
  
    var receiver = await UDP.bind(multicastEndpoint);
  
    var sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any());
  
    receiver.asStream().listen((datagram) {
      if (datagram != null) {
        var str = String.fromCharCodes(datagram?.data);
  
        stdout.write(str);
      }
    });
  
    await sender.send("Foo".codeUnits, multicastEndpoint);
  
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:5));
  
    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
}
```